# Exclude set of records by user_ids that are of a given type. Got the where query, need the opposite

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a  sequel statement that selects what I want to exclude like this:

```
e.where("events.user_id in (?) and type = 'Post'", some_ids)
```

How do I write that statement that excludes those? Can I write it in one line or do I have to store those and exclude those events by id?

some_ids is an array of user_ids

Answer (score 2):

```
e.where("events.user_id not in (?) or type <> 'Post'", some_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

"where not exists" are your three favourite words.  For example,

```
select whatever
from wherever
where not exists 
(subquery goes here)
```

Comment: While it works, it's not necessarily the most efficient (depends on the rest of the query)